# cannot access Hidden field value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this view.html with Django:

```html
{% for item in cart %}
<div class="card rounded-3 mb-4">
   <div class="card-body p-4">
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
         <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
            <img
               src="{{ item.product.product_image.url }}"
               class="img-fluid rounded-3" alt="Cotton T-shirt">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <p class="lead fw-normal mb-2">{{ item.product.name }}</p>
            <p><span class="text-muted">
               {% if item.product.is_service %}
               Service
               {% else %}
               Product
               {% endif %}
               </span> <span class="text-muted">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 d-flex product_data">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ item.product_id }}" class="prod_id">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if item.product.is_service == False %}
            {% if item.product.quantity >= item.product_quantity %}
            <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-2">
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button"
                           class=" changeQuantity quantity-left-minus btn btn-primary btn-number"
                           data-type="minus">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                        </button>
                        </span>
                        <input type="number" id="quantity"
                           class=" align-items-center qty-input"
                           value="{{ item.product_quantity }}">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button"
                           class="changeQuantity quantity-right-plus btn btn-primary btn-number"
                           data-type="plus">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        </button>
                        </span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            {% else %}
            <h4>Out of Stock</h4>
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 offset-lg-1">
            <h5 class="mb-0">$ {{ item.product.selling_price }}</h5>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 text-center">
            <button class="text-danger delete_cart_item">Remove</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And here is the jQuery code:

```js
//    change the quantity in the cart
$('.changeQuantity').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var product_id = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.prod_id').val()
    var product_qty = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.qty-input').val()
    var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/update_cart/',
        data: {
            'product_id': product_id,
            'product_qty': product_qty == null ? 1 : product_qty,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: token

        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response.status)
            alertify.success(response.status)
            //  $('.cart-data').load(location.href + " .cart-data")
        }
    })
});

//delete
//    change the quantity in the cart
$('.delete_cart_item').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var product_id = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.prod_id').val()
    var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/delete_cart/',
        data: {
            'product_id': product_id,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: token

        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response.status)
            alertify.success(response.status)
            //  $('.cart-data').load(location.href + " .cart-data")
        }
    })
})
```

in the first code for (changeQuantity) I could access the product_id... but with the second I couldn't it is just (undefined) ??? ..... but when change the second one to

```
var product_id = $('.prod_id').val()
```

I access it successfully...
my question is why? it is just a same file and code?
and is there a better way to work with those thinks in jquery

Comment: The issue appears to be poorly structured html. In trying to diagnose your code (cleaning it up) I found stray tags (unclosed), Additionally, the delete functionality lives outside of the enclosing 'product data' div so there is no 'closest'. Examine your HTML structure

Comment: `$('.prod_id').val()` "works" because it searches the entire document for `.prod_id` elements, but then gives the your .val() of the *first* one, so won't work for second etc.

Answer (score 1):

`.product_data` is an ancestor of `.changeQuantity` so you can use closest to go from  `.changeQuantity` to `.product_data` but `.product_data` is not an ancestor of `.delete_cart_item` so you cant use closet to select it.
The parent div of `.delete_cart_item` is a sibling of `.product_data` so you can use the method below to get uoyr data.

```
var product_id = $(this).parent().prevAll('.product_data').find('.prod_id').val()
```

Comment: yes, but i solved by just add product_data in div which remove div inside it, is there any problem ?

Comment: Restructuring the html seems like the better solution.